# CSS and HTML that resize the font size based on screen width

Tags: html, css, visualforce

is it possible to resize the font size based on the screen width, so that i always see the full text without having to scroll to the right, even on a mobile phone?
I need to use this CSS on a visualforce page in salesforce.
So i need the text to not wrap based on the screen, but always keep the same ratio.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
<apex:slds />
<style>
    // css goes here
</style>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Field__c}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you try a bit of CSS3? From a quick search, I couldn't see anything saying it won't work. Or do you have to use IE to view the pages?

Comment: Why can't you use modern css if you are using visual force?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, it can't be used only if it's renders as PDF, then i guess i can use css3.

Comment: Ok i made it work, i will post the answer here so that it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >

<apex:slds />
<style>
.parent {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100px;
font-size: 1.3vw;
display: inline;
}
</style>
<div class="parent">
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Field__c}"/>
</div>
</apex:page>
```